# Eclipse formatter for XML like Java

Tags: xml, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In Eclipse I need to format XML like I do on Java with Formatter when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> pressed.

The use of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> on XML does not provide the results that I want.

Is there a tool like: "*Window→Java→Code Style→Formatter*" to do the job?

The: "*Window→XML→XML Files→Editor*" and "*Window→Editors→Text Editors*" lacks a lot of features, like "*Window→Java→Code Style→Formatter→Edit→Indentation→Align fields in columns*" so ther XML result will be like:

```
android:id              = "@+id/textView1"
android:layout_width    = "wrap_content"
android:layout_height   = "wrap_content"
```

I don't care if it's an external plug-in or a lib.
I use Eclipse 4.2.0 Juno for Android development.

Comment: "does not provide the results that I want" ... what *are* the results you want?

Comment: Full custom formating. Like controlling the blank lines, align fields etc.

Comment: I see an option for blank lines...what fields are you looking to align?  Could it be that you're just seeing the Layout editor's formatting, which is different?

Comment: @nitind About "blank lines" you are absolutely right!
About the align fields I edit the question.

Answer (score 2):

Markup languages cannot be formatted as Java code. Despite that, you can assign the default `html` editor with the `.xml` file type as follows:

1. `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations`
2. Select the `.xml` from the top box and assign it to the `Html editor` from the bottom box. Also you can set it as default.

Doing this will enable markup highlighting for all `.xml` files and you can use the default <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> shortcut to format your xml file.

This formatting can be parametrized from `General->Editors->Structured Text Editors`. There are no many options there but it will do the job. Also, you can try using other formatters like the `php` one (I think it requires PDT to be installed to eclipse).

If you are only interesting in understanding the structure of an xml file, than just formatting it:

- You can use one of the many online [xml beautifiers](https://www.google.gr/search?q=xml%20beautifier&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a), or
- Use an [XPath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) tool

Hope that helps

Comment: The: Window -> Preferences -> General -> Editors -> File Associations
is one step forward but it's not realy that I want.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a menu option on the editor's context menu Source -> Format

Comment: The only options avaliable under "Source" are: "Shift Left", "Shift Right", "Cleanup Document", "Format", "Format Active Elements" and "Occurrences in a File", which are all actions and not menus.